# derivative for a vector

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors

Confused about how to get formula from (12.4) to (12.5), which derivative respect to $u_1$? I understand how to calculate derivative for a scalar parameter, but confused how to calculate derivative for a vector parameter like $u_1$, especially when there is both $u_1$ and transpose of $u^T_1$. If anyone could provide a bit more details, it will be great.

The context of the question is from PCA.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By “derivative” they mean the gradient with respect to $\mathbf{u}_1$. That is, if $\mathbf{u}_1 = (v_1,\dots,v_D)^T$, then you compute $(\partial f/\partial v_1,\dots,\partial f/\partial v_D)$.

To find the gradient of your particular function $f(v_1,\dots,v_D)$ given by (12.4), it's easiest to write out the matrix products explicitly in terms of the variables $v_k$. Since the matrix $\mathbf{S}$ is symmetric ($S_{ij}=S_{ji}$), you get
$$
\begin{split}
f(v_1,\dots,v_D)
&=
\sum_{i=1}^D  \sum_{j=1}^DS_{ij} v_i v_j + \lambda_1 \left( 1-\sum_{i=1}^D v_i^2 \right)
\\
&=
S_{11} v_1^2 + 2S_{12}v_1 v_2+\dots + \lambda_1 (1-v_1^2-v_2^2-\dots)
.
\end{split}
$$
Then just compute the partials as usual.

Comment: Thanks Hans, vote up. But in formula (12.5), it seems they have one result, but if we take partial derivative, there will be n results, respecting to each partial derivative? How to combine each of the n partial derivative results? If my understanding is wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: (2.15) is a vector equation, corresponding to $D$ scalar equations.

Comment: Thanks Hans, nice catch and vote up! But I think there might be some other formula we can leverage directly to calculate derivative on a direction (a vector as gradient), so that we can even get from (12.4) to (12.5) directly without scalar variable form as you described? I mean, if the original function is more complicated, written into a form of scalar is far more complex -- if there are some formula to calculate directly from a vector direction, just as how we deal with a scalar variable, it will be great.

Comment: @LinMa: Yes, one can also replace $\mathbf{u}_1$ by $\mathbf{u}_1 + \mathbf{h}$, multiply out, and disregard quadratic terms in $\mathbf{h}$. Then the gradient $2\mathbf{S}\mathbf{u}_1-2\lambda_1 \mathbf{u}_1$ can be read off from the linear terms in $\mathbf{h}$, using that $\mathbf{u}_1^T \mathbf{S} \mathbf{h} = \mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{S} \mathbf{u}_1$ (since $\mathbf{S}$ is symmetric) and $\mathbf{u}_1^T \mathbf{h} = \mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{u}_1$. But I thought the explanation in terms of components was simpler.

Comment: Thanks Hans, your reply is excellent. Vote up and mark your reply as answer.